# Animate each transform property separately on click event using CSS

Tags: javascript, css, css-transitions, css-transforms

> I want that whenever I click on the `div`, it first `translate`, then `rotate` and, finally `scale`. Further, I want to `reverse it back` in the same way when I click again

I have the following code:

```js
$(() => {
  $('div').on('click', () => {
    $('div').toggleClass('clicked');
  });
});
```

```css
div.normal {
  height: 20px;
  width: 100px;
  background: black;
  transition: 2s all;
}
div.clicked {
  transform: translate(100px, 100px) rotate(45deg) scale(2);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class='normal'></div>
```

As you can see, all the transformations are occurring at the same time. But, I want them to occur separately. How do I achieve this?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Not an expert but I think you need to use CSS keyframes. Here's a starting point: https://css-tricks.com/using-multi-step-animations-transitions/

Comment: @DuncanThacker, can you give me an example with click event and CSS keyframes?

Comment: My CSS3 skills are pretty rusty, but I'll give it a go <rolls up sleeves>

Comment: For complex animations I'd recommended TweenMax and [TimelineMax plugins](https://greensock.com/timelinemax)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Decompose your animation using keyframes. Here is a minimally edited version of your code:

```js
var $el = $('#to-animate')
var firstClick = true

$el.click(() => {
  $el.toggleClass('clicked')

  if (!firstClick) {
    $el.toggleClass('unclicked')
  }
  
  firstClick = false
})
```

```css
div.normal {
  height: 20px;
  width: 100px;
  background: black;
}
div.clicked {
  animation: transforms 2s forwards;
}
div.unclicked {
  animation: transforms-2 2s reverse;
}

@keyframes transforms {
  33% {
    transform: translate(100px, 100px);
  }
  66% {
    transform: translate(100px, 100px) rotate(45deg);
  }
  100% {
   transform: translate(100px, 100px) rotate(45deg) scale(2);
  }
}

@keyframes transforms-2 {
  33% {
    transform: translate(100px, 100px);
  }
  66% {
    transform: translate(100px, 100px) rotate(45deg);
  }
  100% {
   transform: translate(100px, 100px) rotate(45deg) scale(2);
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="to-animate" class='normal'></div>
```

**Edit** updated to include ability to reverse the animation (making the code edit less minimal)

Comment: Nice one - I was just working on the same thing. I think you can remove the `transition: 2s all` CSS property.

Comment: @DuncanThacker good catch. Wasn't sure if that was there to transition anything else, but based on the click alone, it won't have any effect.

Comment: To reverse, you should be able to use `animation-direction: reverse` on the non-clicked div.

Comment: @Damon, The animation **should stop** after `scale` and when I click again then, it should **reverse back in the same way**. That is why, I used `toggleClass()`

Comment: @Rahul updated my answer. There is some trickiness with rerunning the same animation twice so I've edited the code a bit more. Note that `transforms` and `transforms-2` are identical, but they essentially need to be separate variables to run in succession.

Answer (score 1):

An idea is to rely on other properties to achieve the same effect and be able to apply different transition

```js
$(() => {
  $('div').on('click', () => {
    $('div').toggleClass('clicked');
  });
});
```

```css
div.normal {
  height: calc(20px * var(--s,1));
  width: calc(100px * var(--s,1));
  background: black;
  position:relative;
  top:0;
  left:0;
  transition: 2s top 4s,2s left 4s,2s width 2s,2s height 2s,2s transform;
}
div.clicked {
  top:100px;
  left:100px;
  --s:2;
  transform:rotate(45deg);
  transition: 2s top,2s left,2s width 2s,2s height 2s,2s transform 4s;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class='normal'></div>
```

Comment: So, according to you there is no way to animate each transform property separately in my case?

Comment: @Rahul alone you cannot since they belong to the same property .. the only way to do with transform is to have 2 animation and more CSS code to achieve what you want